# django 1.10 one app page with a link redirect to another app page

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2, python-3.5, django-allauth

I'm new to django server and trying to build a simple website for user registration. Here is the problem, I create my own app with index.html as my homepage. I also used another user registration app from:

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/allauth

I was trying to add the app to my homepage with a 'sign up' link.  Basically, the account part, and ideally, the link can direct to: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/

However, when I run the server, it gives me error:

```
 Reverse for 'base' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

server result:

Both apps work fine individually, but when I try to add the link to my homepage, the error occurs.

The related code in index.html file in my first app:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'allauth:base' %}">Log In</a></li>
```

The full path for index.html in my project is:

```
 project/app1/templates/app1/index.html
```

The full path for base.html in my project is:

```
 project/allauth/templates/base.html
```

I know I probably need to add a url line in my first app's urls.py file, and a view to show it, but how can I do it? Can anyone help me with this, much appreciate.

Comment: Do you have to use the other registration app? I mean it is easy enough to use native django authentication system.

Comment: I think you're missing the `namespace` keyword in all-auth `include` in your urls settings.

Comment: @Bobby, since I mainly need the email confirmation and the socialaccount function in this app, but yeah, I should try the django auth system first to better understand the concept.

Comment: @gitblame, I tried that by giving each app's urls.py a specific app_name, while it caused other reverse issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `<li><a href="{% url 'allauth:base' %}">Log In</a></li>`

this line uses URL reversing, `'allauth:base'` is the URL patterns, `allauth` prefix is the namespace, `base` is the named URL. You must define the namespace and named URL in the urls.py first.

Define your namespace in project's urls.py file like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^author-polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='author-polls')),
    url(r'^publisher-polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='publisher-polls')),
]
```

Define your named URL in app's urls.py file like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    ...
]
```

all the help you need is in this document: [Naming URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)